# Accessibility issue with text color on dark theme with a light color texture (image) background

Tags: css, bootstrap-4, browser, accessibility, darkmode

I'm on Bootstrap 4 and having a light colour .png image as background of navbar and body, while the footer area is in dark with off-white text colour. The default text colour is black, as the background image is light coloured.

The things get ugly when a user accesses the website on dark theme. The text colour on dark theme gets changed into light colour while the background image remains as light that leaves the text unreadable.

See below the text presentation in light and dark themes:

text on default (light) theme

[image: text on default (light) theme]

text on dark theme

[image: text on dark theme]

Can I keep my text colours unaffected irrespective of the theme of the users? Thanks in advance!

Comment: Can you provide more info on how visitors use a “dark theme”? Chrome has an option to force Dark Mode for web content and Windows has *forced colors modes* such as Windows High Contrast that overrides your CSS colors, but it’s usually best to not try to override those settings as the user may have a reason for so doing. The other option is for users to set their system to dark mode. You can detect that using media queries `@media (prefers-color-scheme: dark)`, either in CSS or JavaScript, and then change the colors and background images as needed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got it fixed by simply using a transparent texture .png in place of a colour-filled texture .png image as background, with an adjustment in `body {background:}` colour.